# Sweet Alert Redirection to URL using ASP.NET Core (default Ok button)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sweetalert, sweetalert2

The below `Javascript` function still fails in pointing to the relevant `URL`, although I cannot see any abnomaly. Hence a puzzlement leading to this post.

```
if(msg) {
if (msg.provider == "sweetAlert") {
    swal.fire({
        title: msg.title,
        text: msg.text,
        icon: msg.icon,
        timer: 5000,
        confirmButtonColor: "black",
        BorderColor: "white"
    }, function(){
        var url ='@Url.Action("Action","Controller")';
        window.location.href = url;
    });
}
```

Thus, any relevant feedback would highly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Best

Answer (score 1):

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Some title',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Go to Google',
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        var url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/';
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

Use `then` function to handle callback. If `result.value` is `true` indicates user click on Okay button.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Some title',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Go to Google',
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            alert('user click on Okay button');
            var url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/';
            window.location = url;
        }
        else {
            alert('user click on Cancel button');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: Grateful to your feedback, particularly in pointing the missing ```then``` function to handle callback. Much appreciated - Thank You.